# Why is this line integral not equal to 0?

Tags: vector-analysis

Given the vector field $$\textbf{F}(u,v)=\frac{av}{a^2u^2+v^2}\textbf{i}-\frac{au}{a^2u^2+v^2}\textbf{j}$$
I've calculated a potential function $$\psi(u,v)=\arctan{\frac{au}{v}}$$
whose gradient $\bf\nabla{\psi}$ is equal to $\textbf{F}(u,v)$. Since $\textbf{F}(u,v)$ can be represented as a gradient of a potential function, shouldn't it be conservative? Thus, shouldn't the circulation along any closed path
$$\oint_C \textbf{F}(u,v)\cdot d\textbf{r}$$
be equal to 0? I've been tasked to compute that integral along the unit circle, but it appears that the answer is not 0. Can someone help me to identify where my reasoning is wrong?

Comment: The domain has a hole in it.

Comment: @amd I can't identify where a hole exists. Could you point me further?

Comment: $\mathbf F$ is undefined at the origin. For that matter, $\psi$ as you’ve written it is undefined along the line $v=0$.

Comment: @amd So if the vector field is undefined at some points, how does one compute a line integral along a path that includes those points?

Comment: Luckily for you, the path along which you’re supposed to integrate doesn’t pass through the origin, although it does surround it.

Comment: @amd Since the path I'm integrating along doesn't include the origin, shouldn't my line integral still yield 0? Excepting the origin, the field is defined everywhere and conservative. Also, going back to your third comment about $psi$, doesn't $\psi=\pi/2$ along the line $v=0$, since the argument of the arctangent goes to infinity?

Comment: Division by zero is undefined, and “infinity” is not a number. Furthermore, for fixed $u\ne0$, the limit of $\psi(u,v)$ as $v\to0$ doesn’t exist, either: the left and right limits differ. As for the value of the integral, for an irrotational vector field to be conservative, the domain must be simply-connected. This isn’t the case here: the integral over a closed path that surrounds the origin doesn’t necessarily vanish. That’s kind of the point of this exercise. Try integrating the simple case of $a=1$ to see what happens.

Comment: @amd I tried computing $\int{\frac{av}{a^2u^2+v^2}du}-\int{\frac{au}{a^2u^2+v^2}dv}$ and got the indefinite integral $\arctan{(au/v)}-\arctan{(v/au)}+C$. Putting in $v=0$ makes it undefined. Does this mean that the integral is undefined? Are line integrals of vector fields that aren't simply connected always undefined?

Comment: Not at all. As you can see from my answer, this line integral is perfectly well defined. Line integrals around holes in the domain of a vector field are often closely related to contour integrals of complex functions around poles. I’m not sure how those integrals in your last comment relate to a line integral of $\mathbf F$, however. That’s not quite the way to find an antiderivative of the vector field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve clearly learned that an irrotational vector field is conservative, but there’s a catch: for this to be true, the domain must be simply-connected. In this case, the vector field $\mathbf F$ is irrotational, but it’s also undefined at the origin—its domain is the punctured plane $\mathbb R^2\setminus(0,0)$. This is not simply-connected, so you can’t expect that its integral over a path that surrounds this hole at the origin automatically vanishes.

To get an idea of what’s going on, look at the simple case $a=-1$, so that $\mathbf F(u,v)={-v\over u^2+v^2}\mathbf i+{u\over u^2+v^2}\mathbf j$. If you sketch this vector field, you’ll see that although there’s no net circulation near any point at which the field is defined—i.e., it’s irrotational—there is a very obvious global circulation around the origin. As well, $\mathbf F$ is everywhere tangent to the unit circle and has constant magnitude along that curve, making $\mathbf F\cdot \mathrm d\mathbf r$ is a nonzero constant so that its integral will be nonzero. Specifically, using the obvious counterclockwise parameterization of the unit circle $C$, we have $$\oint_C\!\mathbf F\cdot\mathrm d\mathbf r = \int_0^{2\pi}\!(-\sin t\;\mathbf i+\cos t\;\mathbf j)\cdot(-\sin t\;\mathbf i+\cos t\;\mathbf j)\,dt = \int_0^{2\pi}\!dt = 2\pi.$$ A slightly more complicated calculation for the general case will produce a similar result.

Note that your scalar potential $\psi(u,v) = \arctan\left({au\over v}\right)$ has some issues that prevent it from globally satisfying $\nabla\psi=\mathbf F$. A big problem is that it’s undefined along the line $v=0$. Moreover, this discontinuity isn’t removable: for fixed $u\ne0$, $\lim_{v\to0}\psi(u,v)$ doesn’t exist: the left and right limits have opposite signs. A function must be continuous to be differentiable, so this $\psi$ fails as a global antiderivative of $\mathbf F$.